# Jquery datepicker : jquery-ui.js:7639 Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker_getInst

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Our web designer used Adobe Muse to generate a responsive page. So that each screen breakpoint has its own DOM elements but those elements are same with other respective elements in another breakpoint.

One of the element is for date of birth field. The designer used `textarea` to represent the field. Knowing that `JQuery`'s datepicker does not work with `textarea` so I changed the element type from `textarea` to `input text` with `datepicker` as the `class`. I changed all the `textarea` related to date of birth field in every screen breakpoint to the same input with the same class.

So that in `JQuery` I can do it like this:

```
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

But unfortunately, when I tried to pick a date from the datepicker view, it returns an error saying `jquery-ui.js:7639 Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker_getInst`

I googled and tried to find a solution. I found the following code and tried it.

```
$('.datepicker').live('focus', function(){
      $(this).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: '1930:'+(new Date).getFullYear()
      });
    });
```

But to no avail.

Anyone knows what caused the error ? and how to solve it ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Following is the break point of 870 screen

```
    <div class="breakpoint" id="bp_870" data-min-width="719" data-max-width="870"><!-- responsive breakpoint node -->
   <div class="clearfix borderbox temp_no_id" data-orig-id="page"><!-- column -->
    <div class="position_content temp_no_id" data-orig-id="page_position_content">
     <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="pu209456_content1"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
     <div class="clearfix colelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="pu209457"><!-- group -->
      <div class="browser_width grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209457-bw">
       <div class="museBGSize temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209457"><!-- column -->
        <div class="clearfix temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209457_align_to_page">
         <span class="clip_frame colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209446_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
         <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209477-4_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <form class="form-grp clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url('spark/regstudent_step2')}}" data-orig-id="widgetu209537"><!-- none box -->

       <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="{{!empty($first_name) ? $first_name : ''}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="{{!empty($last_name) ? $last_name : ''}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="mobile_number" value="{{!empty($mobile_number) ? $mobile_number : ''}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{!empty($email) ? $email : ''}}">
       <div class="clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209556-4"><!-- content -->
        <span class="placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209556-4_0_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       </div>
       <div class="clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209557-4"><!-- content -->
        <span class="placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209557-4_0_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       </div>
       <div class="clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209554-4"><!-- content -->
        <span class="placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209554-4_0_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       </div>
       <input class="submit-btn NoWrap grpelem temp_no_id" type="submit" value="" tabindex="28" data-orig-id="u209555-17"/><!-- state-based BG images -->
       <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-required="true" data-orig-id="widgetu209550"><!-- none box -->
        <span class="fld-textarea actAsDiv rounded-corners clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209553-4"><!-- content -->
        <!--<textarea style="padding-left:30px;padding-top:13px;" class="wrapped-input temp_no_id" name="custom_U209550" tabindex="25" data-orig-id="widgetu209550_input"></textarea>
-->
        <select style="padding-left:30px;padding-top:13px;" class="wrapped-input" id="widgetu209550_input" name="custom_U209550" tabindex="1">
        <option value="">Select a gender</option>
        <option value="">--------------------------</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>

        <label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt temp_no_id" for="widgetu209550_input" data-orig-id="widgetu209550_prompt"><span class="actAsPara placeholder" data-placeholder-for="widgetu209550_prompt_0_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span></label>
        </span>

       </div>
       <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-required="true" data-orig-id="widgetu209542"><!-- none box -->
        <span class="fld-textarea actAsDiv rounded-corners clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209544-4"><!-- content -->
        <!--
        <textarea style="padding-left:30px;padding-top:13px;" class="wrapped-input temp_no_id" name="custom_U209542" tabindex="26" data-orig-id="widgetu209542_input"></textarea>
        -->
        <input id="datepicker5" placeholder="Date of Birth" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="text" style="padding-left:30px;padding-top:13px;" class="wrapped-input temp_no_id datepicker" name="custom_U209542" tabindex="26" data-orig-id="widgetu209542_input"/>
        <label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt temp_no_id" for="widgetu209542_input" data-orig-id="widgetu209542_prompt"><span class="actAsPara placeholder" data-placeholder-for="widgetu209542_prompt_0_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span></label></span>
       </div>
       <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-required="true" data-orig-id="widgetu209546"><!-- none box -->
        <span class="fld-textarea actAsDiv rounded-corners clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209549-4"><!-- content --><textarea style="padding-left:30px;padding-top:13px;" class="wrapped-input temp_no_id" name="custom_U209546" tabindex="27" data-orig-id="widgetu209546_input"></textarea><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt temp_no_id" for="widgetu209546_input" data-orig-id="widgetu209546_prompt"><span class="actAsPara placeholder" data-placeholder-for="widgetu209546_prompt_0_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span></label></span>
       </div>
      </form>
      <span class="clearfix grpelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209534-3_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
      <span class="museBGSize clip_frame grpelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209460_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
     </div>
     <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="pu209531_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
     <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="pu209478-12_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
     <div class="browser_width colelem" id="u209474-bw">
      <div id="u209474"><!-- group -->
       <div class="clearfix" id="u209474_align_to_page">
        <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu209452"><!-- column -->
         <span class="clip_frame colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209452_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
         <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209479-5_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
        </div>
        <span class="clearfix grpelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209528-12_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix colelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="ppu209448"><!-- group -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="pu209448"><!-- column -->
       <span class="clip_frame colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209448_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       <span class="clip_frame colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209463_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       <span class="clip_frame colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209467_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       <span class="clip_frame colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209524_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="pu209569-4"><!-- column -->
       <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209569-4_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209527-9_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       <div class="clearfix colelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="pu209526-7"><!-- group -->
        <span class="clearfix grpelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209526-7_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
        <span class="clearfix grpelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209471-10_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <span class="museBGSize clip_frame grpelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209454_content1"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
      <div class="SlideShowWidget clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="slideshowu209482"><!-- none box -->
       <div class="popup_anchor temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209487popup">
        <div class="SlideShowContentPanel clearfix temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209487"><!-- stack box -->
         <div class="SSSlide clip_frame clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209496"><!-- image -->
          <img class="ImageInclude position_content temp_no_id" data-src="images/sc_tab_10.jpg" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" data-width="166" data-height="250" data-orig-id="u209496_img"/>
         </div>
         <div class="SSSlide invi clip_frame clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209488"><!-- image -->
          <img class="ImageInclude position_content temp_no_id" data-src="images/sc_tab_1.jpg" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" data-width="166" data-height="250" data-orig-id="u209488_img"/>
         </div>
         <div class="SSSlide invi clip_frame clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209494"><!-- image -->
          <img class="ImageInclude position_content temp_no_id" data-src="images/sc_tab_3.jpg" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" data-width="166" data-height="250" data-orig-id="u209494_img"/>
         </div>
         <div class="SSSlide invi clip_frame clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209490"><!-- image -->
          <img class="ImageInclude position_content temp_no_id" data-src="images/sc_tab_6.jpg" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" data-width="166" data-height="250" data-orig-id="u209490_img"/>
         </div>
         <div class="SSSlide invi clip_frame clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209492"><!-- image -->
          <img class="ImageInclude position_content temp_no_id" data-src="images/sc_tab_7.jpg" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" data-width="166" data-height="250" data-orig-id="u209492_img"/>
         </div>
         <div class="SSSlide invi clip_frame clearfix grpelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209498"><!-- image -->
          <img class="ImageInclude position_content temp_no_id" data-src="images/sc_tab_8.jpg" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" data-width="166" data-height="250" data-orig-id="u209498_img"/>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix colelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="pu209535"><!-- group -->
      <span class="clip_frame grpelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209535_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
      <span class="clearfix grpelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209481-8_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
     </div>
     <div class="browser_width colelem temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209480-bw">
      <div class="temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209480"><!-- column -->
       <div class="clearfix temp_no_id" data-orig-id="u209480_align_to_page">
        <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209462-5_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
        <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="pu209472_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
        <span class="clearfix colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209566-4_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <span class="verticalspacer placeholder" data-placeholder-for="page_position_content_8_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
     <span class="browser_width colelem placeholder" data-placeholder-for="u209445-bw_content"><!-- placeholder node --></span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="preload_images">
    <img class="preload temp_no_img_src" data-orig-src="images/u209555-17-r7.png" alt="" src="images/blank.gif"/>
    <img class="preload temp_no_img_src" data-orig-src="images/u209555-17-m7.png" alt="" src="images/blank.gif"/>
    <img class="preload temp_no_img_src" data-orig-src="images/u209555-17-fs7.png" alt="" src="images/blank.gif"/>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked that there aren't any other scripts that might be interfering? That `data-orig-id="widgetu209542_input"` on datepicker5 makes me wonder if the input might be getting replaced by a different instance at some point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It seems that is the case. The auto generated file from Adobe Muse also includes javascript code. But I don't think I can modify the original javascript because it's way too complicated and may cause even more errors. I will try to modify the input and remove some attributes that may be used by the original js. Let's see if it works.

Comment: `live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and was removed in 1.9 [reference](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @telic I found the solution. I have to use the widget id `widgetu209542_input` when assigning the datepicker to the element in JQuery instead of the class to make it work with the existing script and elements.